# How do I talk to ADFS 3.0 from javascript or ionic?

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework, oauth-2.0, adfs3.0

I have an adfs 3.0 server configured to accept oAuth2. 
It was easy with c# to talk to the server using  *WIF*.

However, I'm not sure how should go about using *Javascript?(html5/css/Javascript)* or *(ionic to be precise)*

I googled, did not find any good reference. 
I'm using javascript to talk to my *protected api* which would accept the Oauth2 token from ADFS.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft provides the ADAL library to request security tokens.  This library has been written in many different languages.  For Javascript you can use https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js .  I haven't tried it myself but in essence this library encapsulates the these processes for you.  Here is a reply from Bertocci himself : https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js/issues/222 on usage with ADFS.